# Isn't Unity Transform[] a dynamic array?

Tags: unity-game-engine

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
(wrapper stelemref) System.Object.virt_stelemref_class_small_idepth(intptr,object)

It's been a week since we started Unity, is Unity Transform[] a static array, not a dynamically increasing array without initializing it directly? I thought it was a dynamic array so far, but what type should I declare it to be a dynamic array?

I always got this error because I thought it was a dynamic array. How do I prevent this error in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, an array containing brackets is a static array with a fixed length.

```
Transform[] trns = new Transform[10]
```

If you want to increase the size of the array during runtime, you can use the new keyword to create a larger array.

```
Transform[] trns = new Transform[30]
```

I recommend using 'List'. Because the list is a dynamic array, you can adjust the length of the array during execution.

```
List<Transform> list = new List<Transform>();
```